# Jmeter loadtesting for WebApp -Load not distributed to all API servers

Tags: nginx, jmeter, nginx-config, nginx-plus

I have a webapp to be tested. The current configuration is with 4 API servers with hash method as load balancer.

```
    upstream example{
      hash $remote_addr consistent;
      server abc;
      server def;
       ---
       ---
}
```

While performing the load testing, im observing its hitting only 1 server and not all 4 servers.
I also tried using load balancer methods as "ip_hash","round robin" and "sticky cookie srv_id;" as i have server with nginx-plus but the application is not working as it needs persistent server for completing 1 user session (uses sticky session).

Is there any way to distribute the load to all servers? Or Am I missing out something
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan, it might be the case [JMeter is caching the IP address of the one server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html) and doesn't resolve it on subsequent iterations.

More information: [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps)

Comment: thankyou. I have added DNS cache manager, but still the load is going to only one server. I tried with distributed load generators aswell but still the same. Kindly suggest if there is any other solution